# На какую самую минимальную ширину экрана стоит обращать внимание при адаптивной вёрстке?

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте. Хотел бы узнать на какую минимальную ширину стоит обращать внимание, т.к. иногда бывают картинки и даже при адаптивной вёрстке на малых экранах могут выглядеть не очень, да и стоит ли работать над этим. Возможно сейчас таких экранов в большенстве и не используют. Например в инструментах разработчика есть экран Iphone-5 320px под какой сложновато делать адаптивку.

Comment: Сложновато, но надо. Да и не так сложно, на самом деле. В общем, 320 - это стандарт минимальной ширины, хочется вам этого или нет.

Comment: Вы удивитесь, как всё это будет выглядеть на ultrahd 4k, если не предусмотреть его существование. А там и до 8K не далеко.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока под 320px, иначе на устройствах с диагональю 4 дюйма читать будет не комфортно.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе не так сложно, используй css grid технологию, с ней легко переставлять элементы как надо, а так вообще, чем меньше экран тем больше убирай не нужные элементы, ибо мешают, как разработке, так и просмотру информации пользователю